# Ansible git clone github permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, ssh, ansible

I've been working on this for ~2 hours now, and I'm completely at a loss. I know this question has been asked and answered before, but I'm totally stumped.

I'm trying to clone a github repo onto a virtual machine via ansible.

When I do I get the following error:

```sh
Warning: Identity file /home/REMOTE_USER/.ssh/id_ed25519 not accessible: No such file or directory
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Here is the ansible playbook handling the github cloning:

```yaml
- name: Create SSH Key
  hosts: vm
  remote_user: REMOTE_USER

  vars:
    local_keyfile: /home/LOCAL_USER/.ssh/id_ed25519
    public_key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/LOCAL_USER/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub') }}"
    remote_keyfile: /home/REMOTE_USER/.ssh/id_ed25519
    repository: "git@github.com:GITHUB_USERNAME/GITHUB_REPO.git"

  tasks:

  - name: Add public key to authorized keys
    lineinfile:
      path: /home/REMOTE_USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
      line: "{{ public_key }}"

  - name: Copy SSH Key
    copy:
      src: "{{ local_keyfile }}"
      dest: "{{ remote_keyfile }}"
      owner: REMOTE_USER
      group: REMOTE_USER
      mode: 0600

  - name: Configure SSH to use ansible key for github.com
    template:
      src: templates/ssh_config.j2
      dest: /home/REMOTE_USER/.ssh/config
      owner: REMOTE_USER
      group: REMOTE_USER
      mode: 0644

  - name: Clone repo
    git:
      dest: /home/REMOTE_USER/PATH_TO_REPO
      repo: "{{ repository }}"
      key_file: " {{ remote_keyfile }}"
      clone: yes
      update: yes
```

Steps I've taken to try to fix the issue:

1. Added the public key to authorized_keys on the remote host
2. Added

```
Host github.com
   IdentityFile PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

to the .ssh/config file on the remote host.

3. Created an ansible.cfg file that has:

```
[defaults]
transport = ssh
sudo_flags = -HE

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

4. Ran the playbook as `root` & `REMOTE_USER`
5. Removed the `Copy SSH Key` task

I've messed around with all these settings, and no mix of them works. If I manually SSH into the VM I can run `git clone git@github.com:GITHUB_USER/REPO` and it works fine (but prompts me for the passphrase for my SSH key)

`REMOTE_USER` has permissions for the private key, the directory the repo is being cloned into, authorized_keys, the public key, & the config file.

Everything I've tried that I've read from stackoverflow, other stackexchange sites, and the general internet hasn't worked so far.

I would appreciate any guidance as to how I can fix this issue that doesn't involve using HTTPS for the git clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue locally, and I found the problem is the leading whitespace in the string

```
      key_file: " {{ remote_keyfile }}"
```

If you remove the space after the first quote, it should work.

I should note I tested locally without a passphrase on the key. I'd imagine the passphrase might be an issue for the `git` module.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tomorrow morning!

Comment: This worked! I did have to use a key without a passphrase, and I was able to perform the clone:
1. Without copying my public key to authorized_keys

2. Without setting up the ansible.cfg

3. Without adding the key path to .ssh/config on the remote host 

(for anyone who might come across this question in the future)